# how to display sum of number by this week

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to display sum of number by this week

I have SQL base table name oam

| nas | Mor | Cas | Tat | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 9 | 0 | 1 | 2021-05-26 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | 0 | 2021-05-27 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 2021-05-28 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 2021-05-29 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 2021-05-30 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 2021-05-31 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 2021-06-01 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 2021-06-02 |

and i call information in php using this code

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','data','pass','user');
$result = mysqli_query($conn, '
SELECT SUM(nas) AS value_sum 
  FROM oam 
 WHERE DATE(data) = DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
 GROUP 
    BY DATE(data)
'); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
$sum = $row['value_sum'];
 echo $sum;
```

result is 8. but corect result is 28.

Comment: `SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 7 DAY)` returns 2021-05-26. As per table you posted,its 8 only. How do you say 28 ?

Comment: This is the query, you should be using.
`SELECT SUM(nas) AS value_sum FROM oam WHERE DATE(data) <= NOW() AND Date(DATA) >= DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 7 DAY)`

Here you can get sum of all the values of nas column of where Data column has date which ranges in last 7 days i.e. last week

@Mihaela

Comment: but how its corectly ?

Comment: Looks like you want this>>>  echo array_sum(range(1,$sum-1));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `WEEK` function:

```
SELECT SUM(nas) AS value_sum
FROM oam 
WHERE WEEK(Data) = WEEK(CURDATE())
;
```

For example CURDATE is `2021-06-02` and current week is `2021-05-30` to `2021-06-05`

PHP code:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, '
    SELECT SUM(nas) AS value_sum
    FROM oam 
    WHERE WEEK(Data) = WEEK(CURDATE())'); 

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 

$sum = $row['value_sum'];

echo $sum; // 10 = 4 + 3 + 2 + 1
```

[Execute PHP online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=a0edc2a2317a2ea61f7adcd8ed471cb9&sqlses=c8a9a3d528345b34025d245efc41e1b0&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)